# f# programming the insert function?

Tags: f#

I am trying to implement a function that should inset in order using <, if x exists in S, then S is returned unchanged. The code I wrote below does not output as intended. If I have a set S = [2; 4] and x = [4; 6]. The expected output should be 
[2; 4; 6] where the code below outputs [2; 4; 7]. Any help to fix the issue is appreciated. Thank you.

```
let rec insert x S =
    match S with
    |[] -> x
    |e::rest -> e::(insert S rest)
```

Comment: Are you sure? This code would never output a number that wasn't in the input somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several suggestions to help you in programming:

- Be consistent. You can start with your naming convention: you have `x` in lowercase and `S` in uppercase, that is confusing.
- Use names that are meaningful, to you. Even if they get to be too long, you can shorten them later. In your last line you are calling `insert` on `S` and `rest` but `rest` is part of `S` so that makes no sense. If it was clearer what is what, you surely would spot the error.
- Sprinkle `printfn` in several places so you can actually see what is happening. That way you can figure things out by yourself.

I am rewriting your code following the advice I laid out above. Notice I am not changing the code just the name of the variables and adding some `printfn`s

```
let rec addToOrderedList orderedList listToBeAdded =
    printfn "addToOrderedList %A %A" orderedList listToBeAdded 
    match listToBeAdded with
    | []                        -> printfn "nothing to add, finishing"
                                   orderedList 
    | elem::restOfListToBeAdded -> printfn "adding element %A" elem
                                   elem::(addToOrderedList listToBeAdded restOfListToBeAdded)
```

Notice in the last instruction the recursive call `addToOrderedList listToBeAdded restOfListToBeAdded`. Now it is clear that you are trying to add the `restOfListToBeAdded` to `listToBeAdded` which is not right.

There are other issues with your implementation but I'll let you figure them out on your own, that is part of the learning process. Hint: there is no `<`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Set<'a> type](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Sets_and_Maps). the Set module provides a Set.union function (or + operator) which does what you want to achieve.

```
let insert lst1 lst2 =
    Set.ofList lst1 + Set.ofList lst2
    |> Set.toList
```